# I have override the magento layer.php file but not work

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, overrides, product-collection

I have override magento layer.php file and need to change some method. just like below.

```
public function getProductCollection()
    {
        if($this->getCurrentCategory()->getId()==290){
        $startprice=0;
            $endprice=499;
             $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
                        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                        ->addAttributeToFilter('price', array('gteq' => $startprice))
                        ->addAttributeToFilter('price', array('lteq' => $endprice))
                        ->getData();



        }else{
            if (isset($this->_productCollections[$this->getCurrentCategory()->getId()])) {
            $collection = $this->_productCollections[$this->getCurrentCategory()->getId()];
        } else {
            $collection = $this->getCurrentCategory()->getProductCollection();
            $this->prepareProductCollection($collection);
            $this->_productCollections[$this->getCurrentCategory()->getId()] = $collection;
        }



        }

        return $collection;
    }
```

After this changes got the following error. how to solve this.

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getSetIds() on a non-object in /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer.php on line 306
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should replace

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
                        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                        ->addAttributeToFilter('price', array('gteq' => $startprice))
                        ->addAttributeToFilter('price', array('lteq' => $endprice))
                        ->getData();
```

with

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
                        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                        ->addAttributeToFilter('price', array('gteq' => $startprice))
                        ->addAttributeToFilter('price', array('lteq' => $endprice));
```

Method getData() returns array, non-object value